# Understanding how to implement a Wrapper type for a Stream

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stream

I was wondering if anyone could give me any pointers on the best way to go about handling wake ups when writing a wrapper for a `Stream`.

For context I've got a Byte stream coming in via a HTTP request (using `reqwest`) and I'm doing some filtering and mapping on that stream to handle validation and deserialization. Effectively whenever the inner stream produces a value I want this stream to *(potentially)* emit a value.

** Edit **
An additional caveat is the stream needs to also hold a small amount of state (A `Vec<String>`) that it needs to be able to reference on each poll - *(the columns property)*

---

**The Solution**

This turned out to be me just not understanding how the stream was working under the hood. Rodrigo's answer below was completely correct. I did just need to return `Poll::Pending` from the inner stream, however I was making the mistake of matching on that and returning my own `Poll::Pending` which was why the stream wasn't being appropriately woken up.

If it's useful to anyone, instead of matching on the output of `inner_stream.poll_next()`, I ended up just mapping the `Some` value and returning that to ensure that I was building off the Polls of the inner stream eg:

```
return Pin::new(&mut this.stream).poll_next(cx).map(|data| { ... })
```

Thanks for everyone who commented and helped out!

---

**Context for the original question**

The wrapper type:

```rust
pin_project! {
    #[derive(Default)]
    struct QueryStream<T, S> where S: Stream, T: DeserializeOwned {
        columns: Vec<String>,
        #[pin]
        stream: S,
        has_closed: bool,
        _marker: PhantomData<T>
    }
}
```

The only implementation of `Stream` that I've managed to get to work on the wrapper type is one that spins on the inner stream when it returns `Poll::Pending`. This doesn't seem ideal though as I believe it would block until a value is emitted?

```rust
impl<T, S> Stream for QueryStream<T, S>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
    S: Stream<Item = std::result::Result<Bytes, reqwest::Error>>,
{
    type Item = Result<T>;

    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let mut this = self.project();
        loop {
            if *this.has_closed {
                return Poll::Ready(None);
            }
            match Pin::new(&mut this.stream).poll_next(cx) {
                Poll::Ready(Some(data)) => {
                    // Parsing Logic Here
                    return Poll::Ready(Some(Ok::<_, Error>(resp)));
                }
                Poll::Ready(None) => return Poll::Ready(None),
                Poll::Pending => {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to remove the loop (and changing the `Poll::Pending` match arm to `Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending`) generally results in poll only being called once before hanging, from my very rough understanding of why this is, it's because I'm dropping the reference to the waker when I return from this function, as it's not stored anywhere.

However I'm struggling to work out how to arrange my struct/code to enable the storage of that reference or alternatively what the best way to enable the use of that waker is? Is anyone able to explain how this problem can be solved?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Returning `Poll::Pending` should work. The waker should be managed by the inner `self.stream`. Anyway I find usually easier to implement a `Stream` using `futures::stream::unfold()` and an `async` function. Did you try that?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't - at least I've not managed to get it to work at all. If you return `Poll::Pending` the first `.await` on the stream returns a value, however that's as far as it gets, it hangs from then onwards. If you add debugging you see `poll_next()` never gets called again.

I'm not entirely sure how you would go about using unfold on an existing stream? I can understand how you can use it to leveraging existing state or go from Future -> Stream, but not sure I understand Stream -> Stream. Do you have a sample snippet to hand?

Comment: *"Effectively whenever the inner stream produces a value I want this stream to (potentially) emit a value."* - sounds like you just need [`.filter()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.12/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.filter) or [`.filter_map()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.12/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.filter_map), no?

Comment: What I mean is that, as long as you do not create your own `Poll::Pending` but always forward exactly one from the underlying stream, then I believe it to be correct. If it still does not work for you the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: About a example for `unfold()` take a look at this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b4d9a8a368feeedfb7870cb606655abd), but maybe kmdreko is right and `.filter()` is more appropriate for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the example - `stream::unfold()` seems to get so close, however I'm running into a few issues - one would affect why I believe I can't use the `filter` or `filter_map` approach too.

Comment: Sorry ran out of time with the last message - 1. I seem to be getting some rather long error messages about the stream generator being !Unpin, 2. I do need to carry some additional external state (the stream can own it, but it doesn't have it from the start) through the stream too (a Vec<String>) which each iteration needs to be able to reference